# Draw vertical line in a line chart with LiveCharts

Tags: c#, winforms, livecharts

I am developing a winform application to display a line chart with the use of LiveCharts. How can I draw a vertical line at a certain x coordinate? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could this be what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42590850/13108684

Comment: @ConnorTJ I think it's about WPF. I should simply draw a line at the maximum value of the graph.

Comment: Hi Pado, yeah, the answer at the link was for WPF, but the C# code to actually plot the lines should be re-useable for Winforms with possibly some slight alterations!

Comment: yes, but it's not what i've looking for: i don't need to add a new lineSeries, i only need to draw a simple line (visual element) at a single x coordinate.

Comment: Ahh, possibly take a look at the `Paint` method something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41263864/winforms-chart-draw-a-allowed-area-on-line-chart except you can modify the code to just draw a single vertical line at the X position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found:

```
        cartesianChart.AxisX.Add(new Axis
        {
            //IsMerged = true,
            Sections = new SectionsCollection
            {
                new AxisSection
                {
                    Value = x_best,
                    Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red,
                    StrokeThickness = 3,
                    StrokeDashArray = new System.Windows.Media.DoubleCollection(new [] {10d})

                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).